# Read a txt file from jQuery (304 Not Modified)

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I am trying to load a text file via a jQuery ajax call `$.get` the issue i am receiving is a 304 Not Modified in console.

I am trying to get the data from the text file which will be local to the document it is called from.  In this instance the text file will just contain a single word `master`.  The aim for loading the data is to call a global variable that will trigger certain events based on the text in the text file.

Here is the code in question:

```
var sv_settings;
$.get('settings.txt', function(data) {
    sv_settings = data;
});
```

What am i missing? Why is my browser returning 304 Not Modified ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try tricking the cache:

```
var sv_settings;
$.get('settings.txt?v='+Math.random(), function(data) {
    sv_settings = data;
});
```

This will make your browser think that `settings.txt?v=0.234234` is a different file from `settings.txt?v=0.111222` which we know is not the case.